# Use R fs::dir_ls to match the beginning of file name?

Tags: r, regex, fs

I'm trying to use `fs::dir_ls()` to return the same results as the `list.files()` example below. Ultimately, I'm just trying to return files that start with a specific pattern.

```r
path <- "./path/to/files"
pattern <- "^ABC_.*\\.csv$"

# list files returns the expected output 
list.files(path = path, pattern = pattern, full.names = T)

# [1] "path/to/files/ABC_1312.csv" 
# [2] "path/to/files/ABC_ACAB.csv"

# dir_ls does not return any matching files
fs::dir_ls(path = path, regexp = pattern)

# character(0)
```

I think the issue here is that the scope of each method's pattern argument differs. The `list.files()` pattern is only applied to the `basename()` of the file path, whereas, the `dir_ls()` regexp argument is being applied to the full path. As a result, the `^` regex is being applied to the start of the path, instead of the beginning of each file. Is there a way to limit the scope of `dir_ls()` to only match patterns on the `basename()` of each file similar to `list.files()`? Any other insights are appreciated!

Comment: Interesting point, I can see how that is in contrast to base R's behavior. Can you change your pattern to be either `"/ABC_.*\\.csv$"` or perhaps `paste0(.Platform$file.sep, "ABC_.*\\.csv$)`? (I feel it's unlikely to have a path-separator as part of the real filename.)

Comment: Related to [this](https://github.com/r-lib/fs/issues/227)

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for the suggestions. Yes, both of these patterns return the desired result. I guess I'm just having a difficult time accepting that `/` can be used to match the beginning of a file name instead of the standard `^` approach.

Comment: Your only other alternative (unless its devs change their minds) is to retrieve all files and use `grep("^...", basename(fullpaths), value=TRUE)`. This defeats the efficiency of doing the matching as low-level as possible, but might ease your minor aversion to `/`.

Comment: presumably you can also do something like `regexp = fs::path(path, pattern)`? Should prevent worries about `/`.

Comment: @CalumYou, I really like this approach. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [**issue**](https://github.com/r-lib/fs/issues/227) on GitHub:

> you need to modify your regular expression to match the full path then, or use a filtering function that only looks at the basename.

Use

```r
pattern <- paste0(.Platform$file.sep, "ABC_.*\\.csv$)
```

You can also do something like

```r
regexp = fs::path(path, pattern)
```